# How to setup ChessX to tell the name of the current opening?

Tags: opening, software

I have ChessX 1.0 for Mac OSX. Is there a way for it to tell the name of the current opening position?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, post a feature request on chessx.sourceforge.net, as ChessX only displays eco codes. But this can easily be changed, as the names are part of the eco file loaded at startup.